# I want to set an asp.net's label with a blank value to "<blank>" with javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

We have code in our website that does a comparsion to what was stored in the database with what the user types in the textbox.  This functionality works as is.  But, I wanted to add some code to to set a empty string value that shows up in the "lbl_hiredate_change" and set it equal to the string "blank".  I added the if statement with the comment "//my addition" in the below code.  Can someone suggest something that will work (this doesn't).  I only want to convert the "" to "blank" at runtime, and don't want that saved in the database.

Thanks,
Brad.

ASP.Net Code:

```
<div>    
    <asp:TextBox  ID="tb_hiredate" CssClass="showOriginal required date" 
     title="Please enter the date this person was hired" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Panel ID="show_hiredate_changed" CssClass="showOriginalLine" runat="server">
      (was: <asp:Label ID="lbl_hiredate_changed" CssClass="showOriginalValue was-label" runat="server"></asp:Label>)
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input.showOriginal').change(function (e) {
        showOriginal($(this));
    });
});

function showOriginal(theControl) {
var thePanel = theControl.siblings('.showOriginalLine');
var theWasLabel = thePanel.find('.showOriginalValue');
if (theControl.val() == theWasLabel.html()) {
    thePanel.css('display', 'none');
}
else {
    //my addition.
    if ($('.was-label').val() == '') {
        $(this).val('blank');
    }
    thePanel.css('display', 'block');
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `text()` instead of `val()` Read more about [**val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/), [**text()**](http://api.jquery.com/text/), [**html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
 if (theWasLabel.text() == '') 
 { 
   theWasLabel.text('blank');
 }
```

Comment: You got me on the right track. I needed to use this:  if (theWasLabel.text() == '') { theWasLabel.text('blank');} your code didn't work for me.